# AH01797: client denied by server configuration: ........../trust.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vps

I am having this server error logs
[access_compat:error] [pid 325472:tid 22641249400576] [remote 66.249.66.38:58818] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home3/cur37674/oinglesdescomplicado.com.br/trust.php

My website got a malware a few weeks ago, I had to call the support to help me eliminate the virus, but since then my website hasn´t been the same...

WP Rocket was unable to modify the .htaccess file due to lack of write permissions.

Now I also got some errors on google ads, saying my website has gotten compromised...

I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me

I haven´t tried much, but I would expect to solve this permission access problem, I guess it could be a problem with php? Not sure

Comment: We can't tell _what_ the support might have done to try and help, so you should probably go and ask them.

Comment: If this is a WordPress, then what is `/trust.php`? Do you have stand-alone PHP script laying around _within_ your WP installation? I am getting the exact same error page for `https://oinglesdescomplicado.com.br/foo.php` - which should likely not actually exist, I suppose.

Comment: _"WP Rocket was unable to modify the .htaccess file due to lack of write permissions."_ - maybe you should see to it that you get that fixed first of all then. **IF** you have already taken measures to ensure that your site will not get compromised _again_. Otherwise, you'd probably just be opening the same security hole that allowed the attacker access the first time, again.